# PCA plot did not work in single cell RNA-seq

Tags: r, scrnaseq, bioconductor

I run plotPCA for single cell RNA-seq data, while I get error message (I use R 4.0). I attached the code and error message here. Did anyone know the reason and how to deal with it. Thanks!

```
library(pcaMethods)
library(SC3)
library(scater)
library(SingleCellExperiment)
library(pheatmap)
library(mclust)
set.seed(1234567)
deng <- readRDS("deng-reads.rds")
plotPCA(deng, colour_by = "cell_type2")
```

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : invalid subscript 'type' in 'reducedDimNames(<SingleCellExperiment>)'
'PCA' not in 'reducedDimNames(<SingleCellExperiment>)'
```

I also get error message when I run the code as below:

```
colData(deng)$tSNE_kmeans <- as.character(kmeans(deng@reducedDims$TSNE, centers = 8)$clust)
```

```
# Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x), : 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

Comment: I solve the first error for PCA, while have no idea about the second one. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty obvious. There is no PCA data in the respective slot of the SingleCellExperiment that `plotPCA` could use, at least it is not called `PCA` which by default is expected. Use `runPCA` first, please read the manuals of `scater` and `scran` first, they have step-by-step code.

Comment: Thank you for your reminding. I follow a tutorial from Sanger institute and they use plotPCA(deng, colour_by = "cell_type2") without error message. While the newest scater package may have litter difference. However now I make it work and please see below: deng <- runPCA(deng)
plotReducedDim(deng, "PCA", colour_by="cell_type2")

Comment: If you follow tutorials and refer to them then please provide a link.

Comment: Here is the link: https://scrnaseq-course.cog.sanger.ac.uk/website/biological-analysis.html#clust-methods